# GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived() called only when app is running

Tags: android, gcmlistenerservice

I am trying to implement GCM. Everything works fine except that the onMessageReceived() method gets called only when the app is running.

I searched for solutions but I am unable to find the case that matches mine. My request body for GCM contains only the "to" and "data" parts, not the "notification" part.

This is the body of the request sent to GCM:

```
{"data":{"title":"Test","message":"Test Message"},"to":"ffl3Q260K8E:APA91bG90Ra_CyXdmB4ztcCXYKEMKFliZ_MVpkqYnzUW2Xizcem4iknSt9guKDeEbWYl2YwwEKa7kKVllE0mBRzUOGhO5jJfAM6vuzisq3qqe_hJ1Dy-mpFQat4_ErfKRKRQOJvhKi4q"}
```

This is my GcmListenerService:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        sendNotification(message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and this is the manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.demoapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demoapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.demoapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".services.RegistrationIntentService"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you try with the  <receiver  android:enabled="true"> . It may solve the issue.

Comment: <receiver android:enabled="true"> doesn't solve.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Manifest, the category name `<category android:name="com.example.gcm" />` in your receiver's `<intent-filter>` tag must be the same as your package name. So replace `com.example.gcm` with the package name that you have declared in your manifest.

This will allow your receiver to receive gcm messages when the app is not running.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange. Your config looks fine other than the package name. I suggest you update your question to reflect the correct package name so that other people don't point out the same issue.

Comment: I changed to my package name, also same, whenever I swipe it from my recent app list, GCM no longer working. That's very funny behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your payload is having the 'notification' also beside the 'data'. When app is at background, the message will be send to the message tray.

Something like this example

```
{
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

Kindly refer here for more info: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options.